# How did Thor and Banner know where to go?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

In the middle of *The Avengers*, the team is split up after coming together on the S.H.I.E.L.D. Helicarrier.  Bruce Banner/Hulk end up in an abandoned warehouse.  Thor ends up in a field.  Shortly afterwards, Tony Stark determines Loki's next destination, Stark Tower.  This information is never transmitted to Banner or Thor.  However, both of them show up in New York City and join in the climactic battle.  How did they know where to go?

Comment: Probably the big hole in the sky?

Comment: @DForck42 your comment should be the answer i think.

Comment: Thor magically knew where to find Loki the first time, when he abducted him from the Quinjet. I suppose the same magic could have helped him find Loki the second time, too.

Comment: The question you should be asking is how Harry Dean Stanton got back to earth to work as a security guard after supposedly being killed by the 'Alien' back in 1979? Thought it was interesting the director had Stanton ask Banner if he was an alien. It was a reference which I didn't catch until I was out of the theater.

Comment: There is a huge portal in the sky with creatures coming through them and buildings being destroyed... that would be a good place to start??

Comment: Thor has connections to SHIELD and Bruce Banner knows his way around New York. I'm pretty sure he had access to a TV to watch the news reports on the exact location of The Avengers. :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### How Bruce Banner found the Avengers:

When Banner was aboard the Hellicarrier, his gamma ray search algorithm had worked out where the Tesseract was (Stark Tower), but before he could tell anyone Loki's machinations kicked in and he turned into the Hulk. After he went back to being Bruce Banner, he just found his way to Stark Tower, where the rest of the Avengers had assembled.

### How Thor found the Avengers:

This one's a bit more problematic. Thor seems to have the ability to track down Loki. Witness how Thor knew Loki was held inside the jet after he was captured by S.H.I.E.L.D.. *How* he does that isn't known. So I'm assuming that, however he does it, Thor simply tracked down Loki to Stark Tower.

Comment: Not to resurrect a very old post, but wouldn't the easy answer to "how does Thor find Loki?" be "Heimdall"? That's the latter's job after all, isn't it -- be able to see into the Nine Realms and see everything/everyone?

Comment: @tonysdg This was written back in 2012, but there is actually more weight to your point with Thor Ragnarok, when Heimdall is explicitly seen talking to Thor from across the universe (which is important in the first Avenger film because the bifrost was still destroyed at that point).

Answer (score 9):

Thor magically knew where to find Loki the first time, when he abducted him from the Quinjet. I suppose the same magic could have helped him find Loki the second time, too. (Perhaps Odin infused Mjolnir with some sort of spell to track Loki quickly.)

As for Banner, that one's actually easier to answer. He's the only one who saw the location of the Tesseract on the helicarrier's computer screen, just before Hawkeye blew up the engine.

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate a little Banner was brought in initially to trace the gamma signature from the Tessaract. So i think he would've been easily able to spot the place where the show down is going to be by tracking those gamma signatures of that Loki's sceptre.

As for Thor he is an Asgardian and brother of Loki plus he is the guardian of Earth. So he could've easily sensed the interference and the opening in the sky which brought Loki's army.

I am pretty sure about Banner because Nick Fury points out in the movie that Banner was tracked to join the team to identify the gamma signature from the Tessaract.

Comment: The only problem with that explanation is that Banner did not have any equipment at his disposal where he landed to figure it out.

Comment: But yeah.. if they both landed somewhere reasonably nearby they could have seen the portal. A large hole in the sky with a blue ray going through it is pretty hard to go unnoticed.

Comment: may be he transformed into Hulk and zeroed in on the Gamma source before coming there in human form to remove necessary attention ;)

Comment: I think Banner's ability to sense gamma signatures was more due to his powers as a scientist, which are themselves useless with at least a small bit of actual equipment to work with.

Answer (score 6):

No, remember when right before Hawkeye attacked the S.H.I.E.L.D. ship, Banner gets a hit on the Tesseract and goes "oh my god". That was Stark Tower but he couldn't tell everyone because Hawkeye's bomb exploded and he turned into the Hulk.

Answer (score 3):

Before Hawkeye's arrow explodes, Banner is the one member of the team who walks over to the screen as sees the location of the Tesseract.  He never gets the chance to tell anyone else.

I don't know about Thor.  I found this page by searching for the answer to that question.  i think the theory that he can find Loki is a good one, since he found him on the place (as stated above).